How to maintain consistant formatting of chapter headers using Titlesec with both single and double spaced chapters?
I'm using the titlesec package to create custom chapter headers. I've found that the headers this package produces depend on whether the chapter is single or double spaced.
Most of my document is double spaced, and the formatting of the title headers looks as I intended. However, the table of contents, list of figures, and list of tables are single spaced. The titlesec package formats the headers of these sections differently. I can get around this by making those chapters doubles spaced (the header then looks correct), but I'd prefer that these chapters are single spaced, while the headers have formatting as if they're double spaced. A minimum working example is below:
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}

%%%Titlesec Command
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\bfseries\Large}{\filleft\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\Huge\thechapter}{5ex}{\titlerule\sf\Huge\vspace{0ex}}[\vspace{0ex}\titlerule]


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\doublespacing
\chapter{Chapter 1 Title}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}

When this script is compiled, the chapter title "Contents" has horizontal lines above and below it, although the lines are very close to the text (this is not what I want). The chapter title "Chapter 1 Title" is formatted properly.
If I swap the order of the commands \tableofcontents and \double spacing, the header format is now correct in both chapters, but the ToC is double spaced (which I also don't want).
Is there a way to keep the header of the ToC double spaced, while single spacing the content of that chapter?
